# order by rank , priority and date in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am using the following query for sorting the rows according tot he rank defined

```
select 
   properties.id,
   properties.agency_id,
   properties.created,
   IF(@prev <> properties.agency_id, @cnt := 1, @cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rank, 
   @prev := properties.agency_id,
   properties.refno
   FROM properties
   INNER JOIN agency  ON properties.agency_id = agency.agency_id
   order by agency.priority, rank , properties.created desc
```

i want to rank the latest rows based on 'created' and agency_id. how can i achieve it ???? any help will be appreciated.

```
properties table
id    agency_id    created        refno     sell_price   
1      1001         2013-12-10    A1-1001     1000000
2      1002         2013-12-09    A2-1002     5000000
3      1001         2013-12-20    A3-1001     9000000
4      1001         2013-12-21    A4-1001     7000000
5      1002         2013-12-25    A5-1002     6500000
6      1003         2013-12-26    A6-1003     5600000
```

(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84c0b/1/0)

now i want to sort them on the column created and rank them according to the agency_id. then want to sort it according to the agency.priority. i have defined the priority inside the agency table. like the following

```
 id      agency_id      created        refno     sell_price
           1001        2013-12-21
           1002        2013-12-25
           1003        2013-12-26
           1001        2013-12-20
           1002        2013-12-09 
           1001        2013-12-10
```

Comment: Where are samples of your data and desired results?

Comment: actually its ranking the properties according the agency_id and ordering by priority, i want to rank them according to the agency_id and created , then order by priority.

Comment: Again, where are samples of your data and desired results?

Comment: I don't see a column called `agency.priority`. How do you define agency priority?

Comment: this column is in agency table and i have defined the priority to each agency like 10, 20 ,30 and so on.

Comment: Can you specify precisely how you come up with `rank`? Is the lowest rank-number agency the one with the highest aggregate sales?